# why while type in command Ionic Serve Got Error

Tags: ionic-framework, cmd, ionic3

hello guys i have a project it is ionic and while i open the project and run command prompt and type ionic serve I got Error please help what wrong with .... thank you

```
    C:\Users\Software Engineer\Desktop\App code>ionic serve
     > ionic-app-scripts serve --address localhost --port 8100 -- 
     livereload-port 35729 --dev-logger-port 53703 --nobrowser
  [app-scripts] 'ionic-app-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or 
  external command,
   [app-scripts] operable program or batch file.

   [INFO] Looks like @ionic/app-scripts isn't installed in this project.

   This package is required for this command to work properly. The 
    package provides a CLI utility, but the
   ionic-app-scripts binary was not found in your PATH.

   ? Install @ionic/app-scripts? No
    [WARN] Not installing--here's how to install manually: npm i -D -E 
    @ionic/app-scripts

    [ERROR] @ionic/app-scripts is required for this command to work 
  properly.

   C:\Users\Software Engineer\Desktop\App code>ionic serve
     > ionic-app-scripts serve --address localhost --port 8100 -- 
   livereload-port 35729 --dev-logger-port 53703 --nobrowser
    [app-scripts] 'ionic-app-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or 
    external command,
   [app-scripts] operable program or batch file.

    [INFO] Looks like @ionic/app-scripts isn't installed in this project.
```

This package is required for this command to work properly. The 
package provides a CLI utility, but the
ionic-app-scripts binary was not found in your PATH.

```
  ? Install @ionic/app-scripts? Yes
   > npm.cmd i -D -E @ionic/app-scripts
   npm WARN deprecated browserslist@2.11.3: Browserslist 2 could fail on 
    reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.

   > node-sass@4.5.3 install C:\Users\Software Engineer\Desktop\App 
   code\node_modules\node-sass
   > node scripts/install.js

     Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node- 
   sass/releases/download/v4.5.3/win32-x64-72_binding.node
   Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node- 
  sass/releases/download/v4.5.3/win32-x64-72_binding.node":

   HTTP error 404 Not Found

  Hint: If github.com is not accessible in your location
  try setting a proxy via HTTP_PROXY, e.g.

  export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234

   or configure npm proxy via

  npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080

 > uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall C:\Users\Software 
  Engineer\Desktop\App code\node_modules\uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
  > node lib/post_install.js


   > node-sass@4.5.3 postinstall C:\Users\Software Engineer\Desktop\App 
   code\node_modules\node-sass
   > node scripts/build.js

    Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\Software 
   Engineer\Desktop\App code\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js 
   rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= 
   --libsass_library=
   gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
    gyp verb cli [
     gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
   gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\Software Engineer\\Desktop\\App 
   code\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
   gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
   gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
   gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
   gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
   gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
   gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
   gyp verb cli ]
   gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
   gyp info using node@12.6.0 | win32 | x64
   gyp verb command rebuild []
   gyp verb command clean []
   gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
   gyp verb command configure []
   gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the 
    PATH
    gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
    gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\Software 
    Engineer\Desktop\App code\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
    gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\Software 
    Engineer\Desktop\App code\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
    gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\Software 
    Engineer\Desktop\App code\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
    gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Software Engineer\Desktop\App 
    code\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
    gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Software Engineer\Desktop\App 
    code\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
     gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Software 
     Engineer\Desktop\App code\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
     gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete 
     (fs.js:165:21)
    gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
    gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\Software 
    Engineer\Desktop\App code\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
    gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\Software 
    Engineer\Desktop\App code\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
    gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\Software 
    Engineer\Desktop\App code\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
    gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Software Engineer\Desktop\App 
    code\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
    gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Software Engineer\Desktop\App 
    code\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
    gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Software Engineer\Desktop\App 
    code\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
    gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete 
    (fs.js:165:21) {
    gyp verb `which` failed   stack: 'Error: not found: python2\n' +
    gyp verb `which` failed     '    at getNotFoundError 
    (C:\\Users\\Software Engineer\\Desktop\\App 
    code\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:13:12)\n' +
    gyp verb `which` failed     '    at F (C:\\Users\\Software 
   Engineer\\Desktop\\App code\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:68:19)\n' +
    gyp verb `which` failed     '    at E (C:\\Users\\Software 
   Engineer\\Desktop\\App code\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:80:29)\n' +
    gyp verb `which` failed     '    at C:\\Users\\Software 
   Engineer\\Desktop\\App code\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:89:16\n' +
   gyp verb `which` failed     '    at C:\\Users\\Software 
   Engineer\\Desktop\\App code\\node_modules\\isexe\\index.js:42:5\n' +
    gyp verb `which` failed     '    at C:\\Users\\Software 
  Engineer\\Desktop\\App code\\node_modules\\isexe\\windows.js:36:5\n' +
   gyp verb `which` failed     '    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete 
  (fs.js:165:21)',
    gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
    gyp verb `which` failed }
    gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the 
     PATH
     gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python
     gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\Software 
      Engineer\Desktop\App code\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
      gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\Software 
      Engineer\Desktop\App code\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
      gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\Software 
      Engineer\Desktop\App code\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
     gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Software 
      Engineer\Desktop\App code\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
     gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Software 
     Engineer\Desktop\App code\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
     gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Software 
     Engineer\Desktop\App code\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
     gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete 
     (fs.js:165:21)
     gyp verb `which` failed  python Error: not found: python
     gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\Software 
     Engineer\Desktop\App code\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)          
     gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\Software 
     Engineer\Desktop\App code\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
     gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\Software 
     Engineer\Desktop\App code\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
     gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Software 
     Engineer\Desktop\App code\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
     gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Software 
     Engineer\Desktop\App code\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
     gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Software 
     Engineer\Desktop\App code\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
     gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete 
    (fs.js:165:21) {
     gyp verb `which` failed   stack: 'Error: not found: python\n' +
     gyp verb `which` failed     '    at getNotFoundError 
     (C:\\Users\\Software Engineer\\Desktop\\App 
      code\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:13:12)\n' +
      gyp verb `which` failed     '    at F (C:\\Users\\Software 
      Engineer\\Desktop\\App 
       code\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:68:19)\n' +
      gyp verb `which` failed     '    at E (C:\\Users\\Software 
     Engineer\\Desktop\\App code\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:80:29)\n' 
      +
     gyp verb `which` failed     '    at C:\\Users\\Software 
    Engineer\\Desktop\\App code\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:89:16\n' +
     gyp verb `which` failed     '    at C:\\Users\\Software 
    Engineer\\Desktop\\App code\\node_modules\\isexe\\index.js:42:5\n' +
     gyp verb `which` failed     '    at C:\\Users\\Software 
   Engineer\\Desktop\\App code\\node_modules\\isexe\\windows.js:36:5\n' +
    gyp verb `which` failed     '    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete 
     (fs.js:165:21)',
     gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
     gyp verb `which` failed }
     gyp verb could not find "python". checking python launcher
     gyp verb could not find "python". guessing location
     gyp verb ensuring that file exists: C:\Python27\python.exe
      gyp ERR! configure error
        gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you 
      can set the PYTHON env variable.
      gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Users\Software 
      Engineer\Desktop\App code\node_modules\node- 
     gyp\lib\configure.js:484:19)
      gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Software 
     Engineer\Desktop\App code\node_modules\node- 
       gyp\lib\configure.js:509:16)
     gyp ERR! stack     at callback (C:\Users\Software 
       Engineer\Desktop\App code\node_modules\graceful- 
    fs\polyfills.js:289:20)
       gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:165:21)
        gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17763
        gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" 
         "C:\\Users\\Software Engineer\\Desktop\\App 
         code\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "-- 
         verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "-- 
          libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
           gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Software Engineer\Desktop\App 
           code\node_modules\node-sass
           gyp ERR! node -v v12.6.0
           gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
           gyp ERR! not ok
           Build failed with error code: 1
           npm WARN tslint@5.18.0 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.3.0- 
            dev || >=2.4.0-dev || >=2.5.0-dev || >=2.6.0-dev || >=2.7.0- 
            dev || >=2.8.0-dev || >=2.9.0-dev || >=3.0.0-dev || >= 3.1.0- 
            dev || >= 3.2.0-dev but none is installed. You must install 
            peer dependencies yourself.
            npm WARN tsutils@1.9.1 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.0.0 
            || >=2.0.0-dev || >=2.1.0-dev || >=2.2.0-dev || >=2.3.0-dev 
            || >= 2.4.0-dev but none is installed. You must install peer 
            dependencies yourself.
            npm WARN tsutils@2.29.0 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.1.0 
            || >=2.1.0-dev || >=2.2.0-dev || >=2.3.0-dev || >=2.4.0-dev 
            || >=2.5.0-dev || >=2.6.0-dev || >=2.7.0-dev || >=2.8.0-dev 
            || >=2.9.0-dev || >= 3.0.0-dev || >= 3.1.0-dev but none is 
             installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
            npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: 
                fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\fsevents):
            npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported 
           platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted 
            {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: 
             {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

             npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
             npm ERR! errno 1
               npm ERR! node-sass@4.5.3 postinstall: `node 
               scripts/build.js`
               npm ERR! Exit status 1
                npm ERR!
                npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.5.3 postinstall 
                script.
                 npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There 
               is likely additional logging output above.

                  npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
                  npm ERR!     C:\Users\Software 
                 Engineer\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-07- 
                  22T01_30_20_067Z-debug.log
                  [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess npm.

                   npm.cmd i -D -E @ionic/app-scripts exited with exit 
                   code 1.

                   Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may 
                   provide more information.
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are facing is because node-sass is missing the vendor binary.
You can setup the proxy so it will manage to download the binary online.

Another option is to download the file manually, and set the npm config sass_binary_path property to point at it.

> npm config set sass_binary_path "Your-File-Path"

Once you are done run:

> npm rebuild node-sass

Comment: Can you put your output from the npm rebuild node-sass command and  npm config get sass_binary_path (if you choose that option)